# Unit Testing of vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, integration, integration-testing, system-testing

I am asked to do testing of the project which I've made, the question is like that:

> Testing (Test case designs are to be included separately for Unit testing, Integration testing, System testing; Reports of the outcome of Unit testing, Integration testing, System testing are to be included separately. Also, details of debugging and code improvement are to be included.)

The question is that how am I supposed to do unit testing and how can I show that on my project report.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how am i supposed to do unit testing

The most popular [unit testing frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages) on .Net are [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit), [xUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit.net) and the [Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework) (also known as MSTest).

There is a built-in unit testing project type in Visual Studio, try new project and look in the Test section.

I'd recommend reading up on [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) approaches. There is a *lot* of material out there in books and online. Key advice is to [test behaviour, not methods](http://www.bobmccune.com/2006/12/09/unit-testing-best-practices/).

> how can I show that on my project report

It is common practice to set up [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) for software projects. Continuous integration tools like [TeamCity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) can provide reports on unit test passes and failures through to code coverage on each build.